# Trying to add tableview in nib to storyboard view controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tableview, nib

I am trying to add a tableview in a nib to a viewcontroller in storyboard, so I can perform segues. Currently it's not adding the tableview to the storyboard viewcontroller. Below is the code for the xib.

```
class View1: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var table1: UITableView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadViewFromNib()
 }



func loadViewFromNib(){
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("View1", owner: self, options: nil)


  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showArtists", sender:indexPath)

    print(indexPath.row)
}
}
```

Comment: Where does the error happen? Do you get past the line where you are force casting to UIView? If so, can you put a breakpoint after that line and print out what view1 shows up as?

Comment: View1 is not being added to the viewcontroller. I have custom cells in a nib and I at didselectrowatPath I want it to go to another nib or viewcontroller, either one. I don't know if I am approaching it correctly. How do you recommend I approach this?

Comment: view1 is being loaded from a nib though. And you are force casting it (that's probably causing the crash I assume) but if not, debug it with a breakpoint and double check that the contents of view1 are indeed of type UIView.

Comment: If that is where the crash/error is happening, try loading it like so instead: NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("View1", owner: self, options: nil)

Comment: The error comes when I try to perform a segue, if the nib is in the viewcontroller it should work I will include the didselectrowatindexpath.

Comment: Ok You've mentioned a tableview and a segue now. Where is all of that code?

Comment: Did you try the breakpoint thing I mentioned earlier?

Comment: I got the xib in the viewcontroller, I modified my code (I will update it), but the segue does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91689/discussion-between-valheru-and-blee).